# freeing specific element of struct pointer - C

Tags: c

I have a struct let say

```
    struct packets {
        int tcp_source;
        int tcp_dest;
        char *ip_source;
        char *ip_dest;
        int seq;
        ...
    } *pkts;
```

I am allocating space using `malloc` in `while` loop and inside `while` loop when I done using specific `pkts` (in pointed to by `(ptks+index)`) I need to free it like this:

```
    while (i++ < n - 1) {
        (pkts+i)=(struct packets *) malloc(sizeof (struct packets))
        //shared `i` and signal sending thread to send packet
        ...
    }           
    // Now I need to free `(pkts+i)` like
    while (i < 10)
        free((pkts + i)); //Not working
          //OR
        free(pkts[i]); / Not working either -- in both cases error zsh: abort
```

Question is if I choose to free specific element at time then what is the right way plus what I need if I choose to free all elements at once

Comment: `(pkts+i)=` What is this supposed to do? `pkts+i` is an address of a struct, not a pointer to a struct.

Comment: @Gerhardh I am simply moving inside pointer. that what it serves

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `pkts` as an array of pointers to `struct packets`.

```
struct packets **pkts = malloc(N * sizeof *pkts);
...
for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
  // setting  i-th element
  pkts[i]=malloc(sizeof pkts[i]);
  // accessing i-th element
  pkts[i]-> ...
}
for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
   // freeing individual element
   free(pkts[i]);
   pkts[i] = NULL; // avoid accidental accessing or re-freeing 
}
// freeing whole array of pointers
free(pkts);
```

As mentioned in the comments, you probably do not need to allocate each packets individually. Just allocate an array of packets.

```
struct packets *pkts = malloc(N * sizeof *pkts);
...
free(pkts);
```

If you use C99-compliant compiler and you have a reasonable bound on the number of packets use VLA.

```
struct packets pkts[N]; // that's all
```

Comment: worth to note, there is no way to free all allocated memory at once. user needs to iterate the packets array, and free all allocated memory, then free the array itself

Comment: @EliyahuMachluf can u please explain what is the difference between `struct packets *pkts=...` and `struct packets **pkts=.malloc(...).`

Comment: First one is just a single pointer to struct which is being assigned.    second allocates and array of pointers  which are assigned later

Comment: @Alex , please clarify what you mean by "exception"